# How should I replace drawables?

Tags: java, android

I have an list adapter which is showing an items (drawable + text). 
I added to my code an **RoundImage** class, to replace drawables with the rounded ones. The code is following:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    // cirlce avatars
    ImageView imageView1;
    RoundImage roundedImage;

    imageView1 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.kamil);
    roundedImage = new RoundImage(bm);
    imageView1.setImageDrawable(roundedImage);
    //end circle avatars

}
```

next, in the **onCreateView** I'm using an adapter :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);



        //button --------------------------
        add = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);
        //button --------------------------

        RowBean RowBean_data[] = new RowBean[]{
                new RowBean(R.drawable.kamilk, "Kamil "),
                new RowBean(R.drawable.bartlomiej, "Bartlomiej "),
                new RowBean(R.drawable.krzysztof, "Krzysztof ")
        };
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_style, RowBean_data);
        ListView lista = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lista);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);


        return rootView;

    }
```

but I'm getting an error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.materialdesign/info.androidhive.materialdesign.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

so my question is, how should I do the adapter showing "roundedImage"?

I think the problem is in the line below, I also tried with *getActivity().findViewbyId* but it didn't work too.

```
imageView1 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
```

Comment: Can you please post your complete logs and custom adapter class

Comment: @ArsalImam Here's the code of CustomAdapter http://pastebin.com/rU86UdtP and the whole error's log http://pastebin.com/cVuyGxHw

Answer (score 1):

```
info.androidhive.materialdesign.activity.HomeFragment.onCreate(HomeFragment.java:41)
```

This line is causing crash in your application, I found this line contains the below instruction

```
imageView1 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
```

## Reason of crash

The application is getting crash because your rootView is null in the onCreate method because onCreate() executes first before onCreateView() please check the life cycle of the fragment...!

## Solution

Don't give any instruction in onCreate method, Use the below code,

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

// cirlce avatars
    ImageView imageView1;
    RoundImage roundedImage;

    imageView1 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.kamil);
    roundedImage = new RoundImage(bm);
    imageView1.setImageDrawable(roundedImage);
    //end circle avatars


        //button --------------------------
        add = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);
        //button --------------------------

        RowBean RowBean_data[] = new RowBean[]{
                new RowBean(R.drawable.kamilk, "Kamil "),
                new RowBean(R.drawable.bartlomiej, "Bartlomiej "),
                new RowBean(R.drawable.krzysztof, "Krzysztof ")
        };
        CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_style, RowBean_data);
        ListView lista = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lista);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);


        return rootView;

    }
```

Comment: @krzk, You should have to add your avatar imageview in the same layout

Answer (score 0):

I repost this new answer (and deleted the former because that was pointless).

If your `rootViews` in `onCreate` and in `onCreateView` are different, the `rootView` in `onCreate` is apparently null. That resulted [the error](http://pastebin.com/LWxj0yAi).

And if the `rootView` in `onCreate` is inflated from another layout (I presume [this](http://pastebin.com/8KTj5NiP) name `avatar.xml`) other than the `activity_main.xml` (which is set as the `contentView`), you can inflate it by using `LayoutInflater`.

So, insert **`View rootView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.avatar, null);`** before you use `rootView`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View rootView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.avatar, null);

    // cirlce avatars
    ImageView imageView1;
    RoundImage roundedImage;

    imageView1 = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.kamil);
    roundedImage = new RoundImage(bm);
    imageView1.setImageDrawable(roundedImage);
    //end circle avatars
}
```